# The [rowname] and [columnname] tags have been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

**Tag Counts**

- [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) x200
- [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) x393
- [Intersection between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname+columnname) x8

**Burnination criteria**

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?**

The tag wiki of [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) is:

> The name of rows in a dataframe.

However, only 81 of the 200 questions are tagged [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe)

Similarly, only 74 of the 393 questions in [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) are also tagged [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe)

I believe that these tags don't describe the question. They do not add any useful information.

2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, it is, as it relates to dataframes, but stay with me...

3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. As mentioned above, it doesn't add any information. If you really do need to emphasise that it relates to rows, use the [row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/row) tag. (Note: it seems as though there was a [column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/column) tag, which got synonimised with [columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columns), however now there are no questions in it, so I'm not sure if <1500 rep users can tag their questions with that.)

4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Not really. Less than half of the questions in [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname), and less than a fifth of the questions in [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) are tagged with [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe), which is what it is supposed to be about.

**Conclusion**

There is even [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255669/renaming-last-rows) tagged with only [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname). This could stop answerers from getting to the question. In conclusion, I believe [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) and [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) should be burninated.

Comment: Interesting. Given [tag:columns] is empty, why did we keep [tag:row]? Also [tag:rows] isn't synonimised to [tag:row], which doesn't make sense IMO.

Comment: @Adriaan Synonym added

Comment: I'd expect an SME to give their opinion on the matter, but both tags seems to be about specific functions in a specific language ([looking at one of the wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rowname/info)). If that's the case, the use of having such tags is filtering questions that are about those functions, from questions that just textually have the mentioned functions in the code (which seems like a very good case for filtering).

Comment: @bad_coder - maybe, but it is misused if that is the case: [13x rowname -r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname+-r); [236x columnname -r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname+-r)

Comment: @TheThonnu maybe what's needed is a disambiguation (rename to include the language name in the tag so it isn't misused so often) and clean up, e.g. [columnname \[r\] is:q](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=columnname+%5Br%5D) has 358 Qs while [\[columnname\] \[r\] is:q](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcolumnname%5D+%5Br%5D+is%253Aq) has 141 Qs... So at 39% filtering it can make a good minor tag.

Comment: @bad_coder, I guess renaming them to [r-rowname] and [r-columnname] would help, as there are an awful lot of Python/Pandas questions in [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) for some reason.

Comment: I am professionally an R and Python user, mostly for data science, so I consider myself somewhat of a SME on this kind of thing. I don't see much value in these tags as they currently exist, because the handling of row and column names is totally different in Pandas, R (with variation between R libraries as well), Excel, etc. I agree that if these tags are to exist at all, they should be disambiguated tags like `r-rownames`.

Comment: @shadowtalker  As an SME, would you be interested in taking on one or both of the tasks to go through and remove rowname and columnname from the R questions that are not about the functions `rownames` and `colnames` in R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) and [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) have been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about the R function rownames can be retagged [r-rownames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-rownames)
- Questions about the R function columnnames can be retagged [r-colnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-colnames)
- Questions about dataframes in general can be tagged [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe), preferably with an accompanying library tag (such as [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) for Python)
- [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) overwhelmingly consists of R questions, but [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) does not.

## Progress:

The [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) and [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) tags are in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with these tags, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=rowname+columnname),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Browname%5D+or+%5Bcolumnname%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Browname%5D+or+%5Bcolumnname%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Browname%5D+or+%5Bcolumnname%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Browname%5D+or+%5Bcolumnname%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- Rodgort is still down, and is not expected to come online for the near foreseeable future

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) and/or [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) tags, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) or [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) tags—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) and/or [columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: What's the guidance on [\[columnname\] being used in the context of SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcolumnname%5D+sql)?

Comment: @Bergi Currently, none. AFAIK, there aren't any obvious replacement tags, but I also don't immediately see a need for a replacement, unless there are any functions of importance involved. I have very limited experience with SQL, but from the little I've used it, I'm not aware of anything that would be worth a tag. From a very quick glance at a grand total of 5 questions, I don't see any questions that refer to anything more specific than names of columns, and we don't need a tag for that. Unless an SME comes by and says otherwise (or questions using anything worth a tag appears), (1/2)

Comment: I think just removing it is fine

Comment: I haven't looked at all of these questions, but I think there could be a valid tag for questions about the syntax (and its limitations) of column names in SQL, about how to build them dynamically in SQL queries, and how to find the names of columns in the meta information schema of the database. On the other hand, I wouldn't know what that tag should be, indeed "columnname" is too ambiguous.

Comment: Fair point. I don't have any alternate name suggestions either (though sql-column-names is a low-hanging fruit)

Answer (score 6):

> There is even one question tagged with only rowname.

Which should probably be fixed regardless of whether or not either tag is burninated.  But if rowname is burninated, that question would have no tags.  So it needs to be fixed prior to burnination finishing.  Unfortunately, it's unclear what tags it should have.  For example, is it an R question?  The only clear tag would seem to be [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe), but that's not really descriptive.  It still may be better than rowname.

It seems feasible to remove the tag from the other twelve [rowname -r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname+-r) questions (via edit).  Then [rowname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) could be renamed to r-rownames.  And it may need removed from some of the questions to which it is attached, as not every R question tagged rowname is necessarily about `rownames`.

[columname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columname) is more complicated.  There are more [questions not about R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname+-r) than about R.  But the [R questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcolumnname%5D+%5Br%5D+is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3) should probably be fixed before burninating the tag.  Because right now, we can easily find them.  After burnination, it would be much harder.

Some of the R columnname questions should be r-colnames but others might just get [columname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columname) removed.  Maybe there is an R expert interested in taking on that task?  Have you tried recruiting in the appropriate chat room?

Necessary tasks:

1. Fix the [single question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255669/renaming-last-rows) only tagged rowname to be tagged something else (e.g. [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe)).
2. Fix the other twelve questions tagged [rowname but not R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname+-r) by removing rowname.
3. After 1 and 2, rename rowname to r-rownames (plural because the R function is plural).  This is probably a moderator action, although it would be possible via synonyms and voting.
4. Go through the 141 questions tagged [R and columnname](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcolumnname%5D+%5Br%5D+is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3) and either remove columnname or change it to r-colnames (plural and abbreviated because the R function is plural and abbreviated).

The first three tasks obviate the need to burninate rowname unless people continue to use it.

After the fourth task, it might make sense to burninate columnname.  But IMO, we shouldn't burninate until the R questions are cleaned up.  Because some of them should probably be tagged r-colnames and some shouldn't.

An optional task would be for someone to remove either rowname or r-rownames from the R questions currently tagged rowname.  That could happen before or after the rename.

I see no reason why someone (e.g. you) could not go through and edit the thirteen rowname but not R questions to not be tagged rowname.  That could happen immediately.

Comment: " So it needs to be fixed prior to burnination." - no it doesn't. Burnination is a manual effort, it can be done during the burnination

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine  I added the word "finishing" to clarify the statement.

Comment: I went ahead and removed [rowname](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) from [all the questions which did not have the r tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname+-r). I did check and **they were definitely not [r](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) questions**. The only thing which might need some consideration is [Renaming last rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255669/renaming-last-rows) (the question with only the [rowname](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) tag ->

Comment: I replaced the [rowname](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) tag with [rename](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rename) in this one. Someone might need to just find a better tag to do tag this question with. I think it should be fine, as the question is about renaming, but it would be better for someone else to just double-check that. Thanks!

Comment: I think the way forward now is to rename [rowname](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rowname) so we don't get future questions which are not about [r](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) to [r-rowname](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-rowname). [columnname](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/columnname) might be a bit trickier as most of the questions aren't even about [r](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).

Comment: I've also suggested an edit to the [rowname tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rowname/info). If someone who's above 5k could just approve that, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The function is plural, so it should be r-rownames.

Comment: @mdfst13 - thanks, that was just a typo. I meant r-rownames.