# Why burninate tags? Are we overdoing it?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

I see a lot of posts on meta are around burnination of tags. I wonder if that is the best use of the moderators' and communities' time.

Some of the comments suggest the tags are primarily meant for experts to find questions that need answering. I understand this use case and has been the one reason I used tags for.

Here is a recent burninate thread that got featured - [Should we burninate [rowname] and [columnname]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420433/should-we-burninate-rowname-and-columnname)

My challenge is, are there really experts on rowname and columnname? Are the people eagerly awaiting questions on these tags to answer? Is that thread really worth the time of the 2k views it has got? And the many other burnination threads?

My primary concern is, **we seem to be overdoing it** and we may be better off without burnination, may be. If it is primarily meant for experts who want to find questions to answer, perhaps the burninations should be restricted to tags that are favourited by a minimum number of users. The community should simply ignore the non-popular tags. Mods can take the action they feel appropriate for those tags with a simple vote amongst themselves.

Wanted to know what the community feels about this.

**EDIT**: removed suggestions to keep the discussion focused

Comment: Yes, a review system for tag creation is sorely needed. However, it doesn't suffice by itself. There are also the 63 *thousand* tags we currently have, of which we don't need all.

Comment: If the tag is hidden by default, how does it get applied?

Comment: "*I wonder if that is the best use of the moderators' and communities' time in today's day and age where computing and storage are becoming less and less expensive.*" tag burnination isn't to "free up space". It's to remove bad and misleading information on posts. It's ultimately a maintenance for the *library of knowledge* we curate. If you have a book on chemistry labelled "Science" and "Unicorn" the latter label doesn't match up with the book, nor is it a useful label to have in a library. Hence why it needs to be removed.

Comment: Also worth noting that some tags may start off for some specific purpose but usage turns into a confusing mess and the whole thing is best lit up in flames to save the trouble of maintaining it. For cases where a tag doesn't offer enough information to keep around.

Comment: "*searching text is becoming efficient and the ability to infer tags by the search engines is also becoming easy*" maybe you can explain how am I to follow these tags, then? On SO I can add tags to my custom filter. In what way *exactly* do I get a feed I can review from a search engine where the results match a tag I am explicitly interested in? I also need to know how to ignore certain tags.

Comment: Jugal - don't be discouraged by all the downvotes.  I have never once in my life looked at the tags on a question.  I reach every SO page through google.  Tags are a hobgoblin of little minds.

Comment: @MichaelCurrie "Reaching all questions through google" is probably a decent way to *find* questions however, it seems like a terrible way to review and action incoming questions, though. Would you agree? Or am I maybe missing something in the "use search engine workflow"?

Comment: This also doesn't take into account tags that were once valid, but no longer needed/relevant

Comment: @MichaelCurrie ["Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) As good as external search engines are for finding *existing* Q&A, they are poor for looking for content that still lacks key information – namely answers.

Comment: Tags are classification. While I care very little about classification (I don't think it affects search results much), I think it is great that some folks specialise in it. A future search engine might use the classification to provide much greater search specificity. The current text-based ones are confused by the *"Related"* column to the right (and probably also be the *"Hot Network Questions"*) which links to all sorts of unrelated questions in completely unrelated tags.

Comment: Also, if anything, burnination adds more data to the servers. Deleted questions are preserved, and edited states are as well. It has never been about server storage; if it was, the company could just directly delete whatever content they saw fit to save storage space.

Comment: It is a waste of time, but my alternative, recycling users that create bad tags, keeps getting rejected.

Comment: A recent burninate thread - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420433/should-we-burninate-rowname-and-columnname?cb=1, are there experts on rowname and columnname? Is that thread really worth the time of 2k views it has got? My primary concern was we seem to be overdoing it and we may be better off without burnination. If it is primarily meant for experts who want to find question to answer, the burninations should be restricted to tags that are favorited by a minimum number of users.

Comment: "*My challenge is, are there really experts on rowname and columnname? Are the people eagerly awaiting questions on these tags to answer?*" the tags are being removed. Your questions here only make sense if you're challenging the addition of the tags. Yet you seem to have placed them there to challenge the burnination. I'm not really sure what you really object to now, to be honest. I struggle to understand in what way you believe tag burnination is a problem. Well, other than "wasting time" which, let's be honest, you don't do so why do you care if others do it?

Comment: I don’t get the point of the recent edit at all. That there cant really be any experts for a tag seems like a good reason to remove it. We don’t want to mislead folks into thinking they have added meaningful tags when in fact they haven’t.

Comment: The edit mentions, that if a tag is not popular enough, the burnination can happen within the mods and the community should be involved only for popular tags that a lot of people have favourites. @MisterMiyagi

Comment: @JugalThakkar Mods are not subject matter experts. They are not expected to gauge, for example, whether a tag is rarely used because it is niche or nonsense. Popularity by itself is not a reliable metric for whether there are experts or not; that's why the community is involved.

Comment: Burnination is not for *unpopular* tags. It's for *not useful* tags. In fact, some of the burninations are proposed for *very widely used* tags that nonetheless serve no purpose for classifying content. We do not do burninations just because a tag has few questions or low activity. Take a look at the burnination criteria. It seems more and more like you're proposing a solution to a fictional problem because all the arguments you come up with don't even align with how burnination works. Can you *clearly* explain what problem you think there is?

Comment: @VLAZ "_the tags are being removed_" and replaced with [tag:r-rownames] / [tag:r-colnames] :P see [the retag guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423769/11107541)

Comment: @user replaced when another classifier is more appropriate. The [[tag:rowname]] **is being removed** and for a significant portion of questions it will not be replaced. However, I don't see how this nitpick over a technicality which isn't even relevant helps anything.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback and input. I clearly misunderstand burnination. I shall go ahead and close this question now

Answer (score 19):

The existence of tags that attract mostly off-topic encourages yet more off-topic questions that use those tags. The people who pose those questions point to the existing questions and say "well that question exists with similar tags so why can't mine?"

Moderators can't really view the validity of tags. They are not, nor are they supposed to be, subject matter experts in every technology.

That's why burnination is a community effort: Someone proposes it, it garners enough upvotes to be deemed valid and then it's enacted.

Regarding the specifics of your proposal, what use is a hidden tag? How would anyone use it? If it isn't used, how would it ever reach the threshold where it's reviewed? If it is used by anyone who wants to use it then what does hidden really mean?

Comment: For the hidden tags I don't know what the OP had in mind specifically but I can imagine it is either a tag that is applied by askers but not shown on the questions until the threshold is reached, i.e., repeated creation of the tag, or shown on questions from the beginning but hidden from the to-be-created tag review system until the threshold is reached.

Comment: I meant hidden from searches, unless someone searches for the exact string

Comment: @JugalThakkar so the idea is to create lots of similarly named tags for some new technology and then have some process to merge all them later. Sounds like a lot of work that makes initial categorisation hard.