# The case of the excessive space in burnination banners

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, post-notice, whitespace

Burnination notices have gotten some excessive spacing at the top and bottom:

> [image: Screenshot showing a whole line before and after the text content of the burnination banner]

This has also applied [retroactively to completion banners:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420433/6296561)

> [image: Screenshot showing the same excessive line before and after the banner's text content, but this time on a completion notice]

I have not checked the featured burnination notice, but I assume it's the same thing there. If not, yay?

This is caused by the excessive, empty `<p>` tags  before and after the content:

```
<div class="flex--item fl1 lh-lg">
        <p>
            </p><p>Questions in this tag are being cleaned up in preparation for the tag's removal from the system. Please help by replacing it with more useful tags or by closing and deleting off-topic questions using this tag.</p>
            
        <p></p>
</div>
```

Removing those two brings the banner back to normal:

> [image: Screenshot showing the banner without the excessive spacing]

According to a quick cURL validation, it appears that the two tag pairs are actually being auto-completed by Firefox and Chromium. The raw HTML is:

```
<div class="flex--item fl1 lh-lg">
        <p>
            <p>Questions in this tag are being cleaned up in preparation for the tag&#39;s removal from the system. Please help by replacing it with more useful tags or by closing and deleting off-topic questions using this tag.</p>
            
        </p>
</div>
```

---

As far as I can tell, no other banners are affected. The migration, bounty, lock, and deletion notices render as they should, and the whole lot only contain one `<p>` tag.

Comment: Oddly, it doesn't seem to affect other types of post notices, like [this question has](//stackoverflow.com/q/38061045) and [this answer has](//stackoverflow.com/a/590582). However, it does look like there are some unnecessary `<p>` tags getting inserted into other types of notices, causing visual bugs. Consider the "protected" banner on questions: it has too much padding at the bottom because its contents are wrapped in a `<p>` tag. But only the one displayed to non-logged-in users (repro case [here](//stackoverflow.com/q/44295939); [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stJPQ.png)).

Comment: @CodyGray judging from the initial HTML served, it's even funnier: the notice is wrapped into a paragraph tag which is *also* wrapped in a paragraph tag. Given that `<p>` tags are [not valid content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) of `<p>` tags, the outer tag is separated into an unclosed opening tag and an "unopened" closing tag, which cause the browser to attempt to "fix" that by adding the missing opening and closing tags (hence, two extra empty paragraphs appear).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. This bug is related to [the recent fixes to various spacing issues in post notices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423569/the-case-of-the-missing-space-in-migration-banners). It is fixed now.